# Geopandas installation make spyder and python crash

Tags: installation, python

I use windows 10 and have the last version of anaconda installed (2018.12) with python 2.7. 
When I install geopandas with the command

> conda install -c conda-forge geopandas

Then, spyder is not starting anymore. 
And most of the packages in python are not working 
When i reset spyder I get an error

> Selected binding "pyqt5" could not be found, using "pyqt"

and then

> KeyError: 'pyqt'

I tried to reinstall pyqt, this didn't solve this issue.
I uninstalled and reinstalled anaconda. It works again but each time I install geopandas, python and spyder won't work anymore...

Any hint ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here:
https://geoffboeing.com/2014/09/using-geopandas-windows/

Solution 2 works perfectly.